# Popupmenuitem Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, style.css

In sp2013 i have 2 list Documents and Notes. I have created a tablet device based site with reponsive UI. In the document library list for example the Manage ribbon Group is displayed as popup as shown below.

[image: Document Library Ribbon popup menu]

In the Notes list the same Manage menu is displayed like this

[image: Notes List Ribbon]

On what basis SharePoint change the ribbon as popup and can we Control it or is there way to display the Notes list manage group as popup ?. 
P.S I am also using 
.ms-cui-disabled { Display:none } to disable inactive ribbon button.

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically collapse some actions on the ribbon to make it look friendly if you change the browser window to a small size.

You need to maximize the window of browser, after that you will find it expands actions. When you reduce the browser window size, it will automatically collapse actions.

Comment: I am using Galaxy tab browser and the browser Pixel is the same. User can't resize the browser.

Comment: It will automatically collapse some actions on the ribbon to make it look friendly if  the browser window is in a small size. It is by design.